# Sorting Data from Query

Tags: mysql

How can i sort my data by the last digit. I'm trying to sort a list of locations that look like AQ045A, the last digit being the height level.
So the data is a series of locations

```
AG045A,
AN045B,
AG046B,
AG046C,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STOLOC 
FROM locmst_view 
WHERE wh_id = 'US_3278' 
  AND locsts = 'E' 
  AND useflg = 1 
  AND sto_zone_cod LIKE '%FCC%'
ORDER BY right(STOLOC, 1),
         STOLOC
```

Comment: Thanks i get the following error "Command not properly ended"  here's the current code                      SELECT

               STOLOC

FROM locmst_view

Order by right(STOLOC, 1)

WHERE wh_id = 'US_3278'

        AND locsts = 'E'

        AND useflg = 1

        AND sto_zone_cod LIKE '%FCC%

Comment: add a `'` at the end

Comment: @EGA order by needs to come after the where clause

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help, it's up and running and working as intended.